# jquery ui selectmenu + jscrollpane trouble

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, select-menu

Here is some problem when i using "jquery ui selectmenu" and "jscrollpane" together.

Mousewheel works good, but if i click to scrollpane (".jspDrag") here is sticky mouse.

You can see on link below:

http://htmlfabric.ru/test/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use instead of jquery ui selectmenu - StylishSelect
http://github.com/scottdarby/Stylish-Select/
This plugin works good with scrollpane.